# add geojson from arcgis online API to openlayer map

Tags: ajax, openlayers, geojson

I am trying to get geojson data (point coordinates of a track) using the arcgis online REST API.

```
var data = {
};
// sends AJAX request and forwards the returned data to the visualiser
data.requestJSON = function(requestParameters) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://services.arcgis.com/........=*&f=geojson" ,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            visualizer.sendDataToMap(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
        }
    });
};
```

The geojson data should the be processed in another .js and added to a map.
But I cannot turn the data in a vector.
I found some helpful answers here in the forum, but it still does not work.

```
var visualizer = {}
//prepare the data for visualisation
    visualizer.sendDataToMap = function(jsonData) {

        console.log("jsondata",jsonData);

        var track = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(jsonData)
          });

        console.log("track",track);
}
```

The geojson data from the ajax request shown in the console looks as if the right data is passed.
[image]

But turning it into a vector, according to some code line I found here in the forum, does not seem to work. I do not understand the console.log.

[image: consolw.log]

Can anyone give a hint how to do that?

The console error message looks like

```
ol.js:319 Uncaught TypeError: b.R is not a function
    at mn.l.Va (ol.js:319)
    at Object.visualizer.sendDataToMap (visualizer.js:40)
    at Object.success (dataProvider.js:10)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Or maybe someone has done the same and could provide an example I could try to follow.
Thanks.

Comment: A minified dump of the vector source object isn't very helpful but it does show that the code has reached that line before the error.  What do you do with `track` after that line?

Comment: It seems jsonData is a string you have to parse it using JSON.parse.

Comment: the var "track" should be added to a map. It is supposed to be some bike path.
I am one step further. It seems I needed to convert the geojson geometry in a feature with 
`new ol.Feature(track)`

At least I do not get an error message anymore. Though the bike path is still not visible 
on the map. Maybe something went wrong with the projection.
I tried to reproject but that does not seem to work
```var track = new ol.source.Vector({
   features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})).readFeatures(jsonData)
  });```

Comment: Specifying the projections as options in the readFeatures` is usually more reliable 
`new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(jsonData, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})`  Do you use `track` as the source for an `ol.layer.Vector` then add that to the map?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the projection lines, that helped. At least I can get the extent and zoom to to point where the data should appear. Yes, I would like to use the track as as the source for an ol.layer.Vector. But if I try that directly I get an error: `ol.js:319 Uncaught TypeError: b.R is not a function`. If a ad it to a `ol.Feature(track)` first and use this as source, I get no error. Unfortunately the points dont show up on the map. Must missing something